# How to compress responses from wcf service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, compression, fiddler

I have correctly setup dynamic compression on IIS7, and using fiddler I can see the reduction on content-length when compression is enabled.
i.e. message size was **22882677** - then compressed to **1493531**

using basichttpBinding with maxReceivedMessageSize = **20971520**.

yet, my application still throws an error, saying the max size (20971520) has been exceeded.

my question is, when does the response get decompressed? am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a custom binding (binary)? (Adjust reader quotas to your liking)

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="MyHttpBinding">
    <binaryMessageEncoding>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binaryMessageEncoding>
    <httpTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Or NetTCPBinding?

This will compress the response.